# How to get selected object from "Select" in Angular2 without two-way data binding

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a dropdown with a list of objects. Due to the dropdown including other options it cannot be two-way binded to an array. On selection I want to pass the object to the component, but currently I can only pass the display value.

Here is my template:

```
    <select (change)="doSomething($event.target.value)">
        <option disabled selected>Please select...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">{{ item.description }}</option>
        <option [ngValue]="">None of the above</option>
    </select>
```

And function in the component:

```
    doSomething(item) {
        console.log(item);
    }
```

This results in "Item description", rather than {'id': 4, .... how can I change this?

Comment: Is no form of `ngModel` allowed, or is it just two-way-binding which is not allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (change)="doSomething()">
    <option disabled selected>Please select...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">{{ item.description }}</option>
    <option [ngValue]="">None of the above</option>
</select>

selectedValue: any;
doSomething() {
    console.log(this.selectedValue);
}
```

You can try with this idea.

Answer (score 2):

The `[(ngModel)]` attribute is shortcut of `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`.

Example

```
[(ngModel)]="foo"
```

Is equivalent to

```
[ngModel]="foo" (ngModelChange)="foo = $event"
```

Note that `$event` is the change emitted from the component.

So in your case, you want to do something on `(ngModelChange)`

*component.html*

```
(ngModelChange)="doSomething($event)"
```

*component.ts*

```
doSomething(value) {

    console.log(value)

    // If you want to manually "re-bind" the model,
    // you can re-assign it, this will make sure the ui
    // is updated with the new value
    this.foo = value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select #categoriesCtrl (change)='SelectedValue = categoriesCtrl.value'>
        <option *ngFor="#category of categories" [value]="category.id">{{category.name}}</option>
      </select>
      <button (click)="getValueFromSelect()">Get value</button>
```